# ValueError: Document prompt requires documents to have metadata variables: ['source']. Received document with missing metadata: ['source']. ChainError

Tags: python-3.x, langchain

I am trying to combine ConversationRetreivalChain with Agent. The agent is working fine but when I ask question such as "what is the weather in NY" it will throw the error as shown in the title of the question.
I have given my code as follows. Please help me out.

```
# custom imports
from memory.basic_memory import get_buffer_memory
from vectorstore.load_vectors import get_vector_store
from chains.basic_chains import get_condense_question_chain, get_stuff_documents_chain
 
def get_conversation_retriever_chain(pdf_id:str=None, k:int=10, memory=get_buffer_memory()):
    '''This function creates and returns a retriever chain for Azure AI Search Vector Store'''
    search_kwargs={}
    if pdf_id:
        search_kwargs = {
            "filter":{"pdf_id":pdf_id},
            # "k":1,  by default k is 1, specifying how many documents should be returned from similarity search
            "k":k,
            }
    return ConversationalRetrievalChain(
        question_generator=get_condense_question_chain(),
        retriever=get_vector_store().as_retriever(search_kwargs=search_kwargs),
        memory= memory,
        combine_docs_chain=get_stuff_documents_chain()
    )


from langchain.chains import create_qa_with_sources_chain
from langchain.chains.combine_documents.stuff import StuffDocumentsChain
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
 
# CUSTOM IMPORTS
from prompt_templates.prompts import get_condense_question_prompt, get_document_prompt
from llms.azure_openai_llm import get_azure_openai_llm
 
def get_condense_question_chain():
    '''This function returns condense question chain'''
    return LLMChain(
        llm=get_azure_openai_llm(),
        prompt=get_condense_question_prompt()
    )
 
def get_stuff_documents_chain():
    '''this function returns the stuff documents chain'''
    qa_chain = create_qa_with_sources_chain(get_azure_openai_llm()) # Create a question answering chain that returns an answer with sources
    return StuffDocumentsChain(
        llm_chain=qa_chain,
        document_variable_name="context",
        document_prompt=get_document_prompt(),
    )


 wikipedia = WikipediaQueryRun(api_wrapper=WikipediaAPIWrapper())
 
# custom imports
from memory.basic_memory import get_buffer_memory, get_window_memory
from llms.azure_openai_llm import get_azure_openai_llm
from chains.retrievers.azure_retriever_chains import get_conversation_retriever_chain
 
def get_custom_chain():
    memory = get_window_memory()
    readonlymemory = ReadOnlySharedMemory(memory=memory)
    llm = get_azure_openai_llm()
 
    tools = [
        Tool(
            name="search_vector_store",
            func=get_conversation_retriever_chain(memory=memory).run,
            description="""useful when you need to answer questions using the vector store to answer internal information such as
            1. Donyati: it is a company""",
            return_direct=True
        ),
        wikipedia
    ]
 
    '''this function returns the custom agents'''
    prefix = """Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:"""
    suffix = """Begin!"
 
    {chat_history}
    Question: {input}
    {agent_scratchpad}"""
 
 
    prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
    tools,
    prefix=prefix,
    suffix=suffix,
    input_variables=["input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"],
    )
 
    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
    agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=tools, verbose=True)
    agent_chain = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
        agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True, memory=memory,handle_parsing_errors=True
    )
    return agent_chain
 
agent = get_custom_chain()
agent.run(input="what is the weather in bangalore")
```

The conversationRetreivalChain is working fine. If I ask question following previous question it is throwing the above given error. Please help me out.